# Google Extension with certain popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am a novice.

I am trying to build simple Google extension that has the same style of popup as "Google Dictionary".

When user hit the icon, popup.html will show up with modal box.

User will enter input, hit submit, and the input will be appended to the popup.html temporarily (similar to 2 pictures shown below)

May I ask how should I write popup.html?
Thank you

popup.html with modal box for inputs:

[image: popup.html with modal box for inputs]

For simple case, input are appended to popup.html (so we would expect input under modal box:

[image: for simple case, input are appended to popup.html (so we would expect input under modal box]

Comment: See [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) which explains these basics.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked out the link. But i am not sure how to append the input in popup.html itself. I can use appendChild to append the content, but not sure how to load popup.html again to display it temporarily.

Comment: Um, what? It's just an html page like any other. It's shown automatically when the icon is clicked.